# Different classes implementing same interface goes into constructor

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, abstraction

This is a question about abstraction.

I want to be able to use two completely different GUIs for my application. They are completely different but implements the same interface.

My question is, what will the constructor look like? What type of object goes in the signature?

They do not extend a common parent, so I can't use polymorphism.

controller object wants to be injected with an object which implements Displayable interface.

```
interface Displayable {
    void display();
}

class Display1 implements Displayable {
    public void display() {
        //Shows something Fancy on the screen
    }
}

class Display2 implements Displayable {
    public void display() {
        //write something to console
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        Controller controller = new Controller(new Display1());
        Controller controller = new Controller(new Display2());
        controller.display();
    }
}

class Controller {
    ????? display;

    public Controller(?????? display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    public void display() {
        display.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question: "controller object wants to be injected with an object which implements Displayable interface". So `public Controller(Displayable display) { ... }` etc.